# Separating UI from data/logic

Tags: c#

I am working on a file indexing application that generates file-meta data for use by 3rd party applications. To reduce the working set, I use file filters. Each file filter contains a number of comparators (e.g. CompareFileName, CompareFile Extension, CompareFileDateCreated). All comparators implements a simple ICompareFile interface.

```
public interface ICompareFile
{
  bool Compare(IFile file);
}
```

This works well for raw coding/testing. The problem I have is when trying to create an editor via the user interface. My FileFilter class contains a list of ICompareFile instances. So, my question is, what is the best approach to invoke an editor when a user selects an ICompareFile from a List.

Initially, I was thinking the visitor pattern, however, I may delegate comparators to a plugin class, of which I will supply basic, well-known implementations. In short, the solution must be extensible.

My aim is to separate the representation from the data. For example, I could display a comparator in numerous ways. However, the data is pretty static.

The problem is really about mapping an editor (of some sort) to an ICompareFile instance.

My question, is should the ICompareFile concrete implementation specify its editor or should an external class do this. Personally, I think the latter, (SOLID and DRY principles).

Comment: What do you mean by "*invoke an editor*"?  Presumably every one of your implementation has to do something here, so just add another method to your interface for it.  Once you've done that, just add an implementation of that method on all of your classes that implement the interface, and you'll be able to call the method with any of your comparators.

Comment: By Invoke an editor, I mean just that. A dialog box should present the user with a list of comparator names (File name, File Extension and so on). When use "clicks" edit, I need to create the correct editor based upon the ICompareFile instance. The instance of which come from a list, so I have basically lost type information.

Comment: You haven't *lost* any type information, it's just not accessible at compile-time.  Calls to `GetType()` will return the actual type instead of the interface.

Comment: I appreciate that, but what I don't want is something like...
switch (fileComparator.GetType().Name
{
  case "CompareFileName" : DoSomething(); break;
  case "CompareFileExtension" : DoSomethingDifferent(); break;
  case "CompareFileDateCreated" : DoSomethingEvenMoreDifferent(); break;
}

Comment: If the desire is to split the comparator logic with the interface for editing it, just add a new generic interface with a type constraint (`interface ICompareFileUI<TComparator> where TComparator: ICompareFile`) and have it expose some manner of building and managing the editor user-interface for a particular implementation of `ICompareFile`.

Comment: Will every "plugin class" be responsible for its own UI? I'd like to understand how this is going to be packaged. This will need to have a bearing on how you plan to patternize.

Comment: Not sure at the moment. Currently, I have implemented some basic comparators and UI. However, thinking ahead, I would like 3rd parties to be able to develop their own filters as seen  fir for their own processing needs

Comment: @Karl: then probably you do not want to maintain the relationship between the UI and the comparator in a central place (e.g. via a `dictionary`) but rather, keep the relationship atomic (i.e. UI knows what comparator it is servicing). In which case every UI should dependency inject the comparator it plans to present. Which then means that the picklist you present should really be the list of the available UI's.

Comment: Sorry another clarification: of course pretty much every DI framework allows you to pull up a list of classes implementing a specific interface. So if you have an `IComparatorPresenter` implemented in these UIs, there's your pick list...

Comment: @code4life - Initially I was thinking this. I like to keep code compact, pigeon-holed, dare I say. The thing is, this software is service-oriented and UI oriented. Never really been involved in UI development, mainly middle-tier, back end etc. Really appreciate your input though! I actually do like the idea of a central place to control this. Should make debugging easier when the need arises

Comment: @code4life - not sure how that really works. Are you saying that when a user adds a new comparator, I create an object that contains the Comparator and the object. Maybe a UIFileComparator object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use a [Factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) pattern.

In your Factory you will register concrete classes and their corresponding UI classes, such as:

```
public class FileCompareUIFactory{
// pseudo code, needs work
  private Dictionary<Type,Type> registered = new {
    { typeof(FileCompareNames), typeof(FileCompareNamesUIView)}
  }
  public void Register<C,V> where C: IFileCompare, V: View{
    registered[typeof(C)] = typeof(V);
  }

  public V GetView<C,V>() where C:IFileCompare, V: View {
    // cache already instantiated if needed
    return (V)(Activator.CreateInstance(registered[typeof(C)])
  }
}
```

You can also make the Factory a singleton and require all plugin file comparators to register in the factory

```
public class FileCompareUIFactory{
  private static FileCompareUIFactory _instance = null;
  public FileCompareUIFactory Instance{
    get{ return (_instance = _instance ?? new FileCompareUIFactory()); }
  }
  protected FileCompareUIFactory(){ }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem very *extensible*.  You won't be able to add new comparators (or their editors) without modifications to the code.

Comment: @JoshuaShearer pressed <Tab><Enter> by habit, ended up with a prematurely published answer

Comment: @StenPetrov: not a big fan of `Activator.CreateInstance`. How will you handle dependency injection requirements? So many pain points from this approach.

Comment: Excellent, that seems like a fairly robust solution to a fairly complex problem. Best is that if I do delegate to plugins, the "plugin developer" just needs to call Register with the Comparator and the editor. Nice, succint solutions, many thanks

Comment: @StenPetrov Ah, this is much better.  I originally thought you were suggesting using a collection initializer to map the classes at compile-time, but I'm glad I was mistaken.

Comment: @code4life Absolutely! Not a fan of it either, but it's there for simplicity's sake. I would go with it until it doesn't work, at least it's one place where the View is obtained, so even if you refactor it the rest of your UI code won't know

Comment: I must say, this is a great use of the factory pattern. To think I have been developing software for over 15 years, stumped me this one did. Thanks guys, for your help

Comment: @StenPetrov: lemme be the devil's advocate: what if we just didn't use a factory pattern at all, and used pure dependency injection oriented SRP approach? The classic patterns are dying out these days because they orient towards chunky large blocks of code, wherease SRP drives towards smaller and smaller blocks of code (kind of like lego blocks, lol)...

Comment: @codeForLife - For my solution, I do not need fancy stuff, like dependency injection. I need a solution to solve a particular problem. I think sometimes, one can over think a problem. Just my input, no offence and all :-)

Comment: I was thinking about the same thing - as what @code4life suggested (considering dependency injection) I've used really small libraries that gets the job done, like simpleinjector, which is amazingly efficient at what it does. And it's pretty simple to wrap your head around.

Comment: @code4life please feel free to express your idea in an answer. While in principle I agree - the best design would rely on IoC etc, simplicity is a feature I personally value greatly. For the needs of the OP I perceived I believe the simplest and most straightforward solution to be a Factory. As these needs evolve the Factory offers one-stop refactoring. Basically nothing is lost

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) here because you are creating an algorithm whose behaviour is assembled by the user. Your `ICompareFile` interface would be the inferface for the strategies, and your filter would contain a collection of these based on what the user has selected.

Comment: I considered this, but wasn't to sure how to code against my requirements.  Could you supply pseudo-code as to how I might use the Strategy Pattern? Thanks.